# Why SPI Master mode frequency is half of bus frequency?

Tags: spi

I was reading about SPI [here](http://www.not2fast.com/electronics/6808/09SPI.pdf) On Slide 2, It says,

Maximum Master mode frequency = bus frequency/2
 Maximum Slave Mode frequency = bus frequency.

My obvious question was Why?

P.S. This document is by Motorola, So We can rely...And I have read similar statements in other presentations too.

Answer (score 4):

The MCU in question doesn't have a PLL to increase the clock frequency nor does the SPI controller tap a non- or less-prescaled clock, so the fastest it can toggle SCK is once per cycle. One cycle to set and one cycle to reset means that it runs at half the E frequency.

Comment: Pretty clear and concise +1

Comment: Since each cycle of the bus clock should itself have two edges, what difficulties would exist with having each edge of the bus clock trigger an edge of the SPI clock?

Comment: Not difficulties per se. Straight economics. It's cheaper to toggle each cycle than to recognize transitions and toggle then.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams "Master Mode Frequency" indicates what? Is it the Clock Frequency TO the Master uC?

Comment: @Swanand: It's the frequency of the SPI clock generated by the master.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Then What is bus frequency?? I was thinking Bus Frequency is nothing but SCK Frequency!